# What does it mean for two morphisms with different sources and targets to be isomorphic?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

The standard definition of a subobject relies on the following definition: we call two morphisms $f : X \rightarrow A, g : Y \rightarrow A$ with the same target isomorphic if there exists an isomorphism $u : X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f = g \circ u$. In my eyes, in most texts, this definition is asserted almost by fiat, without diving into what this actually means and why this is a reasonable definition. It's not obvious to me that this is a reasonable definition, for several reasons.

One issue with this definition is that it's not obvious to me why you need it at all - why we can't just define subobjects as isomorphism classes of objects that have monomorphisms into the target in question.

But my larger problem is this. It's obvious what the corresponding definition of isomorphism is between morphisms that share the same source, but what about morphisms that share neither a source nor a target? I would expect that the natural definition would be to say that $f : X \rightarrow A, g : Y \rightarrow B$ are isomoprhic if there exist two isomorphisms $u : X \rightarrow Y, v : A \rightarrow B$ such that $f = v^{-1} \circ g \circ u$. The benefit of this definition is that I believe it flows naturally from the preorder on morphisms in which we define $f \preceq g$ iff $f$ factors through $g$, as the equivalence. However, this definition of isomorphism of morphisms doesn't actually appear to say the same thing as the above

This definition appears - to me - to the notion of isomorphism in the [twisted arrow category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/twisted+arrow+category), also called the category of factorizations: two morphisms are considered however, when specialized to the case $A = B$, this doesn't actually appear to say the same thing as the previous definition, as we have an extra automorphism tacked on to the end.

So is there a way to generalize isomorphism of morphisms that share the same target to isomorphism of all morphisms? If not, why not?

Comment: I think [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, how would you distinguish between two subobjects that are the "same size" but are different subobjects? Your proposal here would make no distinction between $\{2x:x\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{p\in\mathbb{N}:p\textrm{ is prime}\}$; i.e. this would give you only the *cardinals* of subobjects.

Comment: @Matematleta: It might be; I can't honestly tell. Do you think you could flesh out the connections between subobjects and monos in the arrow category, perhaps motivating the standard definition of the subobject?

Comment: Matematleta's link is what you're looking for, as you've written it. The notion of isomorphism for arrows with the same target $A$ is just isomorphism in the category $\mathcal{C}/A$; and the notion of isomorphism of arbitrary arrows that you propose is exactly isomorphism in the arrow category of $\mathcal{C}$, of which $\mathcal{C}/A$ is a subcategory.

Comment: @Malice - it’s not obvious to me that that’s true, because of what I said above about there being an extra automorphism involved in the isomorphism in the arrow category. That is, it seems to me like two morphisms f and g are isomorphic in the arrow category if f=vgu, where u and v are iso, which should mean that for two morphisms that share the same target, we have f=vgu where v is an automorphism. This appears to me to be more general than f=gu alone, but perhaps that’s not actually true?

Comment: The case of isomorphism in $\mathcal{C}/A$ is the restriction of isomorphism in the arrow category to the case where $v=id_A$. You could have a category with the same objects and let $v$ be an arbitrary automorphism of $A$, that's a perfectly well defined notion of isomorphism. But it's not usually the one we're practically interested in.

Comment: There's no way to give a definitive answer to "what is an isomorphism between two arrows" unless you can give an account of *what category they are objects in*; then the question of what isomorphism is is settled at once. But since there is not a unique choice of category, there is not going to be a unique choice of notion of isomorphism. All I claim is that the notion of isomorphism *you define* does have, as a special case, isomorphim in $\mathcal{C}/A$.

Comment: Okay. Well, from my perspective, this definition of isomorphism between morphisms is clearly more reasonable than the one used to define sub objects, as it generalizes in this fashion. I suspect that it gives you the same idea of sub objects. So I’m confused about why people don’t use this one instead.

Comment: "Reasonable" in what sense? You haven't expressed anything about what problem you see with the usual definition of subobjects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88585/discussion-between-malice-vidrine-and-billy-smith).

Answer (score 1):

One way to motivate the definition of subobjects is that it works in familiar categories. For instance, in $\mathbf{Set}$, every subobject of a set $S$ has a unique representative which is a subset of $S$. In particular, two distinct subsets of $S$ are never isomorphic, which would fail under either of your other two proposals. In fact, for $\mathbf{Set}$ the notion of "isomorphism classes of objects admitting a mono into $S$" and "isomorphism class of arrows into $S$" are equivalent, since if $T$ and $T'$ are (without loss of generality) subsets of $S$ and there exists a bijection $\varphi: T\to T'$, then we can always extend $\varphi$ to an automorphism of $S$ making the arrows $T\to S$ and $T'\to S$ isomorphic.

It's the notion of subset that we want to generalize in defining subobjects, for several very good reasons. The collection of subsets of a set has a rich algebraic structure: it's a complete Boolean algebra. Furthermore, functions between sets induce three morphisms of Boolean algebras which encode first-order logic. Most of this story generalizes to an arbitrary locally Cartesian closed category such as a topos, and some of it generalizes to a huge range of categories satisfying weaker properties. Your proposals amount to considering the set of mere cardinalities at most that of $S$, which has no such interesting structure.